Package Manager | Solution Package - URL
I am trying to build a custom package and wanted to try the new feature 'Solution Package'.
Below is what I have tried so far.

Packaged 2 journeys. Downloaded the package as JSON.
Created a Code resource as JSON and uploaded the JSON code from prev step. Published.
Created the Installed package and added the 'Solution Package' component and added the URL of JSON code resource.

However, upon trying to deploy this custom Solution package, though I can see this new package, but I get this error upon deployment.




Does anyone how what URL / where does this URL should lead to? what I am doing wrong here!

Event the official doc link is NOT working.

Based on the documentation about hosting packaged items, specifically the first bullet point, I would guess that your packaged solution is not hosted somewhere that is publicly accessible. Can you host the JSON somewhere else, perhaps just temporarily?

Thanks Mark, for finding this link... I will try to host the JSON on GitHub n try... will share feedback after verifying

Thanks Mark!!! I confirm, that when hosting the same JSON on Github worked [which din't work from Web studio, surprisingly]... though the official doc says You can host your packaged solutions in a secure location, such as Amazon S3, GitHub, or another publicly accessible location.... you can move your comment to Answer, so the community gets the solution.

++ Hosting the JSON on OneDrive also did not work either.!

Based on the documentation about hosting packaged items, specifically the first bullet point, I would guess that your packaged solution is not hosted somewhere that is publicly accessible.


Upload the JSON file to a public endpoint that will remain static.


Can you host the JSON somewhere else, perhaps just temporarily?
